# Zenity, поискслов.рф и кириллица

Tags: кириллица

Имеется скрипт на bash: http://paste.ubuntu.com/14198559/. Всё хорошо, но часто zenity выводит странные закорючки, причём посреди текста. [image: демонстрация закорючек] Если заменить вывод с zenity на обычный echo, то в консоль всё правильно печатает. Есть ли способ от этого избавиться? Опробованы iconv и enconv, не помогают.

Comment: где-то, например, удаляются байты, а не символы. в случае utf-8 это легко приводит к подобному результату.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, а почему тогда терминал выводит всё правильно?

Comment: если фантазировать, то, возможно, процессы, формирующие эту картинку, и процессы, запущенные из эмулятора терминала, получают чуть разные значения переменных окружения, имеющих отношение к локали.: `LC_*`, `LANG*`.